# Intel igb driver packet loss on Debian Linux 6.0

Tags: linux-networking, network-monitoring, drivers, debian-squeeze, intel

I am running Debian Linux 6.0 (2.6.32-5-amd64). My network NICS are Intel 82580 Gigabit running with the IGB network driver version 3.3.6 (firmware version 3.2-9).

I tested the performance and I noticed massive packet drops.

My test is simple: tcpreplay a file to the IGB interface and run tcpdump on the other side to verify that all packets have arrived.

Even with small throughput I experience many drops.

I switched ports to an old e1000e driver, and everything worked like a charm.

I tried doing the following and i got the same results:

Downgraded the driver version installed the sorceforce igb driver installed PF_RING with igb support Played with snaplen, and buffering I upgraded the kernel version to the latest 3.2.5 from kernel.org

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank You

Comment: did the answers help?
also want to buy this nic for debian 6.0

Answer (score 1):

IGB Cards often work sluggish with their default IRQ assignment. You might want to set CPU affinity.
Intel provides [this document](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-controllers/82575-82576-82598-82599-ethernet-controllers-interrupts-appl-note.html) that guides through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the newest Intel NIC driver as a kernel module and use that instead of the stocker.  It has worked wonders for me.